# 2003 Chevy Tahoe Service Brake Light appears periodically

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, tahoe

I have a 2003 Chevy Tahoe (Z71) with 240k miles on it.  I had to rebuild the front brake lines last summer and do a bit additional work on the front line last November.  I also have an issue with the ABS where they will kick very rarely when I am going less than 5 mph and creeping up to a stop.  I believe this is an issue with a sensor firing in my driver side front tire.

Twice in the past 2 months, out of nowhere the "Service Brakes" has come on with a warning tone.  Both times the pressure on the brakes have been fine and they have worked.  Both times were while I was moving very slowly/in a parking lot.  Both times the warning went away upon restarting the car.  Both times when I tried to use a code reader it came back with no issues.

What can I do to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked the fluid level in the master cylinder? Also, is this a Hydroboost system or regular brakes?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 fluid level seems pretty good (it doesn't look low from the top reservoir) and I don't believe I have a Hydroboost system.  Could this be because I did a bad job bleeding the lines the last time I had to refill/do work on it?

Comment: I don't think a bad bleeding job would be causing this ... you'd most likely have a spongy brake pedal if that were the issue. For your edification, the Hydroboost system is the one which replaces the older style vacuum assist with a hydraulic style assist. It has high pressure lines running from/to the power steering pump. It would pretty easy to recognize if you know what you're looking for.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I do believe I have a hydroboost system.  The pedals on the truck are loose, and always have been.  In my experience that's somewhat expected considering the age and make of the vehicle

Comment: You must have the powered adjustable pedals then as well. I had an '04 Suburban Z71 I bought new. Great truck. I never experienced any issues as you've described. Just trying to know exactly what we are dealing with here. How does the power steering feel? Any issues with steering or does it make any noises when you are turning?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Nah, steering is good.  From what I can tell even when the warning goes off, there is no difference in brake responsiveness.

Comment: I wonder if you have a sensor going bad, then.